# Discontinuous limit function and uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis

The sequence I am working with is this, in the interval [-1,1]:

$f_n (x)= \begin{cases}-1,-1\leq x\leq-\frac{1}{n}\\[2ex]nx, -\frac{1}{n}<x<\frac{1}{n} \\[2ex]1, \frac{1}{n}\leq x \leq1\end{cases}$

We can show pretty easily that this converges pointwise to the function

$f (x)= \begin{cases}-1, x∈[-1,0[\\[2ex]0, x=0 \\[2ex]1, x∈]0,1]\end{cases}$

I would like to find the intervals in which this converges uniformly. It can't converge uniformly to a discontinuous function, so obviously we have no uniform convergence in the interval [-1,1]. However, when it comes to showing convergence in ]0,1], can I somehow use the uniform limit theorem here as well to show that the sequence cannot converge uniformly?

Comment: the intervals are not correct in the first expression. They miss the end points. but not important

Comment: Are you familiar with Egorov theorem?

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with measure stuff yet

Comment: Yes sorry Physor, I should have included them you are right. And no Sebastian I am not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re right that you can use the uniform convergence theorem (in the contrapositive) to rule out uniform convergence. On all of $[-1,1]$, uniform convergence + continuity of the $f_n$ would imply continuity of $f$, which is false as you point out. To answer your question about $(0,1]$ specifically, yes the same argument works. Uniform convergence in $(0,1]$ plus ordinary convergence at $0$ would imply uniform convergence on $[0,1]$ (hopefully it’s clear why; adding a finite set does not affect the uniformity). But the limiting function is not continuous on $[0,1]$ so the convergence could not have been uniform.

Comment: If I got it right, it doesn’t affect it because if you add finite points, you can just take the biggest N between the one in the uniform convergence definition and the N in the definition of pointwise convergence of those finite points, so that this biggest N will work for the uniform convergence of the whole set. Thanks a lot, for some reason I really couldn’t think of this.

Comment: Yes, exactly. __

Answer (score -1):

**hint**

For $ x\in (0,1]$ and $ n $ great enough, we will have $$x>\frac 1n \;and \; f_n(x)=1$$

thus

$$f(x)=\lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(x)=1$$
then
$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=0 \; if \; x\ge \frac 1n $$
and
$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=1-nx \; if \; 0<x<\frac 1n$$

Comment: Are you sure the convergence is uniform? If we let x vary anywhere between 0 and 1, we will always find some x such that x<1/n, so the supremum is |nc-1| for some c in (0,1/n) , which is a divergent sequence. Anyways my question was a different one.

Comment: @SamueleMonitto No, there will be n such that $1/n<x$ not as you said $ 1/n>x$!!!

Comment: Don't forget that $ 1/n$ goes to zero and will be smaller than any $x>0$.

Comment: Yes, but the supremum is with respect to x

Comment: @SamueleMonitto There will be uniform convergence in $[a,1[$ with $ 0<a<1$.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the effort. This was also the result I got, even though my question was a bit different and more theoretical, but I still appreciate the time and the answer. I should have mentioned that I already had the solution and was looking for the answer to the theoretical dilemma more than the actual answer to the problem